# installing/configuring and running sshguard on debian

Tags: debian, systemd, sshd, safety

I am trying to install/configure and run sshguard on debian, I want to check if  brute force attacks happen on my server.

I have installed it via apt-get, then I installed systemd and followed the following instructions for configuring https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Sshguard (but those are for archlinux). when I type `systemctl enable sshguard`
it does not work and I get `Failed to issue method call: Unit name sshguard is not valid.`

I know this should be a routine task, but it is the first time I have to work with daemon. This stuff is very new to me and I am lost in the documentation. I would like to configure the thing in a way that it default: it bans temporarily ip after 4 failed attempts and of course I would like to start the service at boot.

Maybe I can entirely forget about it because I intend to allow passwordless login (via public key exchange)

---

when I start `sshguard` with `/etc/init.d/sshguard start` , I get

```
[....] Starting sshguard (via systemctl): sshguard.serviceFailed to issue method call: Access denied failed!
```

Comment: What does `sudo service sshguard start` return?

Comment: `sudo service sshguard restart` works `[ ok ] Restarting sshguard (via systemctl): sshguard.service.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to manage services on Debian is to use the aptly named `service`:

```
$ sudo service sshguard status
$ sudo service sshguard start
$ sudo service sshguard restart
$ sudo service sshguard stop
```

To make a service start on boot, you can use `sudo sysv-rc-conf` which allows you to choose which services are active on each [runlevel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runlevel):

[image]

On Debian, the default runlevel is 2 so if you want a particular service to run on boot, activate it for runlevel 2.

Comment: `sshguard` has already enabled runlevel 2,3,4,5. what does it mean?

Comment: @simona it means that it should start automatically next time you boot. Since `sudo service sshguard start` [worked correctly](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/94262/installing-configuring-and-running-sshguard-on-debian/94286?noredirect=1#comment143307_94262), it should also be running now.

Comment: I don't see this command on Debian 7, has it been deprecated ?

Comment: @valentt you might need to install it `sudo apt-get install sysv-rc-conf`.

Answer (score 0):

on Debian, daemons are started via:

```
/etc/init.d/sshguard start
```

Comment: how do I start it at boot?

Comment: it will automatically be started.

Comment: how can I check if the process is running?

Comment: Calling the init scripts directly is deprecated, use `service` instead.

Comment: @simona `/etc/init.d/sshguard status` or `service sshguard status`